# Identify $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need help to identify $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4)$.

I've been solving such problems in an approach like:

$$
2(x^2-3)=2x^2-6, x(2x+4)=2x^2+4x \\
(2x^2+4x)-(2x^2-6)=4x+6, 2(2x+4)=4x+8 \\
(4x+8)-(4x+6)=2
$$

What shall I do next, please? Thank you.

Simon

Comment: Hi Simon, maybe add a few of your thoughts to this (I think good!) problem. This will help it be well received.

Comment: If you don't want a question marked as a duplicate, then you need to ask a question that can't be answered simply by copying the answers from the other post. For example, "I don't understand this specific aspect of (insert link to an answer you want to understand), can you explain it in more detail?"

Comment: good Simon. We have $2\in (x^2-3,2x+4)$ and $(x^2-3,2x+4)=(x^2-3,2x+4,2)=(x^2-3,2(x+2),2)=(x^2-3,2)$

Answer (score 1):

we have $2=2(x^2-3)+(2-x)(2x+4)$ and then $(x^2-3,2x+4,2)=(2,x^2-3)$

$\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2-3,2x+4) \cong\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^2-3)\cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2-1) \cong  \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x-1)^2 \cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x)^2 $

Comment: I think your last isomorphism is incorrect.  Mod $2$, we have $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)^2$, so $x-1$ is nilpotent in the quotient.  $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has no nonzero nilpotents.

Comment: @Quasicoherent, thank you, you are right. I will edit my comment

Comment: @Simon, we  have the theorem $R[x]/(I) \cong (R/I)[x]$, so $\mathbb Z[x]/(n) \cong \mathbb Z_n[x]$,

Comment: @Mustafa, Thank you! I read elsewhere it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, $\mathbb Z_2$ is a finite field of order $2$, so $\mathbb Z_2= \mathbb F_2$.

Comment: the ring $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2)$ consists of $4$ element.

Comment: @Mustafa, Thank you! I guess you mean $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2)$?

Answer (score 0):

First divide $x^2-3$ by $x+2$, dividing by a linear polynomial is the same as evaluating at the root of the linear term, so $x^2-3=4-3=1$. Thus $x^2-3=q(x)(x+2)+1$ for some $q(x)$. Multiplying by 2, and rearranging, we get $2(x^2-3)-q(x)(2x+4)=2$. Hence $2\in (x^2-3,2x+4)$, so since $2\mid 2x+4$, we have 
$$(x^2-3,2x+4)=(x^2-3,2x+4,2)=(x^2-3,2).$$

Then $\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}\ZZ[x]/(x^2-3,2)\cong \ZZ_2[x]/(x^2-3),$
since the kernel of the natural map $\ZZ[x]\to \ZZ_2[x]/(x^2-3)$ is $(2,x^2-3)$.
Then $x^2-3\equiv x^2+1=x^2+1^2\equiv (x+1)^2\pmod{2}$, so
$$\ZZ_2[x]/(x^2-3)\cong \ZZ_2[x]/((x+1)^2).$$ 
Then by a change of variables, $$\ZZ_2[x]/((x+1)^2)\cong \ZZ_2[x]/(x^2).$$

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to simplify this further. The ring has four elements, $0,1,x,x+1$, only 0 and 1 are idempotents, since $x$ is nilpotent, so $x+1$ is a unit. Thus the ring is not a product of smaller rings.

Comment: Hi, I wonder how do you get $0, 1, x, x+1$. And why does $(x^2-3, 2x+4) = (x^2-3,2)$ instead of $(x^2-3, 2x+4) = (x+2, 2)$ since $x^2-3 = (x+2)(x-2) + 1$

Comment: @col Well to get the elements you just list them out, starting with the degree 0 things, $0$ and $1$, the only two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2:=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and then proceed to the degree 1 things, $x$ and $x+1$, and then you might proceed to degree 2 things, $x^2$, $x^2+1$, $x^2+x$ and $x^2+x+1$, but $x^2\equiv 0$ in this ring, so these are all equivalent to one of the elements listed earlier, and the same goes for any higher degree polynomial.

Comment: @col As for why you don't have $(x^2-3,2x+4)=(x+2,2)$, it's because the right hand side doesn't contain $x+2$. If it did, it would contain $1$, so the quotient would be 0.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, do you mean $(x^2-3) = (x+2, 1)$ for your second response?